# exc_bad_access on [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]

Tags: ios, nsdate, exc-bad-access

I'm getting weird behavior out of `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]`.

I have the following function:

```
-(void) insertRow{
NSTimeInterval timeNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
if (timeNow - secondsSinceTableViewScroll <0.5){
    [self insertRow];
    return;
}

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.itemsToFollow count] - 1];
[self.tableView insertSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

which is a callback from an `ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished`.If I put a breakpoint in the code, it works fine.  If I just try to run the code, I get an `exc_bad_access` on the line:

```
NSTimeInterval timeNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

`secondsSinceTableViewScroll` is an ivar declared in the header and set like this:

```
 secondsSinceTableViewScroll = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the exc_bad_access when there is no breakpoint?

Thanks

**Only thing I could find**

I was checking the time like this:

```
-(void) insertRow{
end = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
if(end-start < 0.05){
    [self insertRow];
    return;
}

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.itemsToFollow count] - 1];
[self.tableView insertSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I'm sure somewhere it says you can't have back to back calls of timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate and that's why it was crashing (this kind of recursive loop was a pretty bad idea anyways).

So use a while loop, or better yet an NSTimer.

Thanks for the help though

Comment: I'd put money on it being a red herring! The code above looks fine. Something somewhere else is causing the bad access. Have you run the Analyzer? Are zombies enabled? If they don't throw up anything then it's time to do some Leaks profiling in Instruments.

Comment: +1 for posting an actual stack overflow issue on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[self insertRow];
```

to

```
[self performSelector:@selector(insertRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: It will prevent you from getting a stack overflow

Comment: Even with the delay set to 0? (I guess it takes some time to call evaluate the method?)

Comment: Yes, it delays the method call until a subsequent run loop interation. It prevents recursion. Here are the docs on what is actually does. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_

Answer (score 2):

Your symptom suggests you're actually crashing on another thread. Do you have other threads running? Check the backtraces for all your threads. The above is on the main thread, correct?

---

EDIT: You're recursing too quickly and overflowing your stack. Half a second of "as fast as you can call yourself" is going to overflow your stack very quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that.  This line of code is being executed on Thread 1 and the exc_bad_access comes at that line.  Thread 1 is the only one with anything in it in the debugger.  Is there something else you'd like me to check?

Comment: There is no backtrace. It says "unable to load last frame".  I've moved on to using an NSTimer instead of this flag method.  I'll post an update.  Thanks for the idea though